# Numerically solve constrained optimization (scipy.optimize), how to express the constraints?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints, python

I am trying to construct a solver for the following problem:

Given $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$, the objective can be written as:
\begin{align}
&L(\hat{x}) = argmin_{\hat{x}} ||A \hat{x} ||_1 \\
&\textrm{s.t.} \quad \hat{x} = x + \ker (A+I)
\end{align}
where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

As a simple example I have the following:
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

In this case the constraint is:
\begin{equation}
\hat{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a free parameter.

Now clearly if I solve this system by hand I get the optimal solution by setting $c=1$ which gives me 0 in the objective.

My attempt at solving this generally in python is thus far unsuccessful. So far I have tried to use scipy.optimize, but I am having trouble writing the constraints.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

x0 = np.asarray([1,-1])
A = np.asarray([[0,1],[1,0]])
I = np.identity(2)
kernel = scipy.linalg.null_space(A + I)

def objective(x):
    E = np.linalg.norm(A @ x,1)
    return E
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(objective,x0) # Solving the optimization, without the constraint

# constraint = ?
# res = scipy.optimize.minimize(objective,x0,constraints=constraint)
```

Comment: This seems more a question of (computer) programming than mathematics...?

Comment: It is certainly borderline I agree. However, I think that mathematicians who are into constrained optimization are probably better at answering the question. 
The second reason that made me decide to post it here rather than stackoverflow is the fact that stackoverflow does not interpret mathjax, which means there is no good way to ask math questions there.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to do this. There might still be better ways to do this, but at least this seems to work.

First I realized that this function was non-differentiable due to the L1 norm, and thus I changed the optimization algorithm to cvxpy

In cvxpy I could solve the problem as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import cvxpy as cp

# def objective(x):
#     E = np.linalg.norm(A @ x,1)
#     return E


def objective(x):
    E = cp.norm1(A @ x)
    return E

def constraints(x,a,kernel,x0):
    C = 0
    for i,ai in enumerate(a):
        C = C + ai * kernel[:,i]
    return x == x0 + C


n = 2
x0 = np.asarray([2,-1])
A = np.asarray([[0,1],[1,0]])
I = np.identity(n)
kernel = scipy.linalg.null_space(A + I)
nf = kernel.shape[-1]
x = cp.Variable(n)
a = cp.Variable(1)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(objective(x)), [constraints(x,a,kernel,x0)])
# prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(objective(x)), [x == x0 + a * kernel[:,0]])
prob.solve()

print(f"Solution is: {prob.status}")
print(f"Exposure ={prob.value:2.4f}")
print(f"portfolio ={x.value}")
print(f"a ={a.value}")
```